# Python PyQt5 - Convert QTime to python time object

Tags: python, strftime, qtime, qtimeedit

I have to solve this error:

```py
day_frequency_parameters = self.main_self.ui_scheduled_transmitions_create_window.daily_one_time_timeEdit.time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
AttributeError: 'QTime' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

where `daily_one_time_timeEdit` is a QTimeEdit object.

Is there any way to convert QTimeEdit or QTime to python time object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a time string from QTime

```
time_str = self.main_self.ui_scheduled_transmitions_create_window.daily_one_time_timeEdit.time().toString('%H:%M:%S')
```

and create a time object from it:

```
import datetime

time_str = "14:32:15"
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M:%S')
time_obj = datetime_obj.time()
print(type(datetime_obj), datetime_obj)
print(type(time_obj), time_obj)
```

output:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'> 1900-01-01 14:32:15
<class 'datetime.time'> 14:32:15
```

I'm sure you can also do this directly with msec, so you don't have to create a string first.